# Create a SEL with an object passed into it

Tags: objective-c, selector

I know how to use:

```
[self method:object];
```

But is it possible to get a SEL object of this?

```
SEL method = @selector(method:object);
```

Doesn't work.

Thanks :)

Comment: Selectors are nothing more than method signatures - they don't come with the objects you pass as arguments. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I need to get a reference of a selector with the object passed into it - because using [self method:object]; won't cut it for this :(

Comment: @BoltBlock A selector isn’t really a method signature since it doesn’t encode types. A more accurate definition is that selectors represent method names.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A `SEL` is just the selector - the name of the message that's sent. To capture a specific instance of that message, its arguments, and its return value as an object, you need to use [NSMethodSignature](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMethodSignature_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and [NSInvocation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSInvocation_Class/Reference/Reference.html). An example, based on your hypothetical `-method:object` above:

```
NSMethodSignature *sig = [SomeClass instanceMethodSignatureForSelector:@selector(method:)];
NSInvocation *inv = [NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature:sig];

// Assume that someObject is an instance of SomeClass
[inv setTarget:someObject];

// Assume an "id object" declared elsewhere.
// Also note that self & _cmd are at indices 0 & 1, respectively
[inv setArgument:&object atIndex:2]

// Some time later...
[inv invoke];
```

Note that, because an NSInvocation is an object, it doesn't have to be invoked immediately. It can be stored for later use, and usually is - there are far easier ways to send a message if one wants to do so immediately. Cocoa's standard undo/redo machinery, for example, is based on storing and invoking NSInvocations.

Comment: Does this mean [inv invoke]; will call the method?

Comment: Yes, exactly - it will do the equivalent of `[someObject method:object]`.

Answer (score 0):

A @selector is something that is of another method or function.

Take this for an example:

```
-(IBAction)timerStart {
timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.0
target:self
selector:@selector(targetMethod:)
userInfo:nil
repeats:NO];
}

-(void)targetMethod:(id)sender {
[timer invalidate];
timer = nil;
}
```

As you can see, the selector (targetMethod:) is being called to action after two seconds of the NSTimer is run. The targetMethod: is a (void)function:(id)sender and therefore that is run.

In your case, what I think you're trying to accomplish is

```
[self performSelector:@selector(methodName:)];
```